# React-Native-Android: Pressing a button that will change the text depending on the button pressed

Tags: react-native

Hello there I am still currently working on my simple calculator and I've got this set of codes that does the computation or functions/events

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        firstInput: '',
        secondInput: '',
        sum: 0,
        difference: 0,
        product: 0,
        quotient: 0,
        result: 0,
    };
}


//CALCULATIONS FORMULA

calculateSum = () => {
    const { firstInput, secondInput } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        sum: Number(firstInput) + Number(secondInput)
    });
}

calculateDifference = () => {
    const { firstInput, secondInput } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        difference: Number(firstInput) + Number(secondInput)
    });
}

calculateProduct = () => {
    const { firstInput, secondInput } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        product: Number(firstInput) + Number(secondInput)
    });
}

calculateQuotient = () => {
    const { firstInput, secondInput } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        quotient: Number(firstInput) + Number(secondInput)
    });
}



//stores input from user
storeFirstInput = (number1) => {
    this.setState({firstInput: number1})
}

storeSecondInput = (number2) => {
    this.setState({secondInput: number2})
}
```

and this is the text that I want to change depending on which button is pressed

```
<View style={styles.answerContainer}>
                {/****** ANSWER HOVERING TEXT ******/}
                <Text 
                style = {{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 30,
                color: '#242582',

                }}> 
                ANSWER: 
                </Text>

                {/****** RESULT OF USER INPUT ******/}
                <Text 
                style={styles.answerText}

                > 
                {this.state.sum}
                </Text>

            </View>
```

I've got 4 buttons namely +,-,* and / (sum, difference, product and quotient)

```
<View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                {/****** ADD BUTTON CONTAINER ******/}
                <View Style={styles.addButtonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity Style={styles.addButtonDesign} 
                        onPress={this.calculateSum}
                        >
                                <Text style ={styles.buttonText}> + </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                {/****** SUBTRACT BUTTON CONTAINER ******/}
                <View Style={styles.subtractButtonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity Style={styles.subButtonDesign}
                        onPress={this.calculateDifference}
                        >
                                <Text style ={styles.buttonText}> - </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                {/****** MULTIPLY BUTTON CONTAINER ******/}
                <View Style={styles.multiplyButtonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity Style={styles.mulButtonDesign}
                        onPress={this.calculateProduct}
                        >
                                <Text style ={styles.buttonText}> * </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                {/****** DIVIDE BUTTON CONTAINER ******/}
                <View Style={styles.divideButtonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity Style={styles.divButtonDesign}
                        onPress={this.calculateQuotient}
                        >
                            <Text style ={styles.buttonText}> ÷ </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
```

and this is where the problem comes in! Whenever I press the -,* or / button it doesn't display the correct formula it always just displays the sum. Is there any way to do an IF statement somewhere in the code where IF buttonpressed is - it will put in {this.state.difference} in the text section of my code? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer after researching for a while it seems that the mistake was purely on my end. 
i changed my previous code to this

```
calculateQuotient = () => {
    const { firstInput, secondInput, result } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        result: Number(firstInput) / Number(secondInput),

    });
}
```

and  the text result to this

```
{this.state.result}
```

it now stores the value to which button I press